# Product gallery disappear after page load

Tags: magento-1.9, jquery, gallery, conflict

I have a problem with the [product page](https://www.apepazza.com/it/jade-4850.html). After the page load all the resource, all the product gallery images disappear except for the first one (each product have 4/5 pictures).
I try to add

`<script type="text/javascript">var $ = jQuery.noConflict();</script>`

in the footer and the gallery works fine. By the way the "Add to Cart" Button stop working.

[image: This is the gallery before all the page resources were loaded]
I can't find the issue/conflict with the image gallery.

Thanks

EDIT: Clearer explanation + image

Comment: checked it is working fine.

Comment: I have also checked it and its working fine, please check with clear cache.

Comment: Yes working fine

Comment: I clear all the cache. I try with Chrome/Safari/Firefox/Edge. I can see only 1 image on the gallery. At first when you load the page you can see all the 4/5 images of the gallery; after the page is fully load you can see only the first image. Check the [screen](https://pasteboard.co/GQRIUwP.png)

Comment: it seems you have set default product on page load, so after page load product images are also changing accordingly, hence it is showing images of the selected product only.